Resizable panes with resize cursor not functioning as expected
I'm trying to create two resizable panes side by side in HTML, where users can adjust the size of each pane by dragging a resize handle. I've added CSS to display a resize cursor when hovering over the handle, and I've implemented JavaScript to update the width of the panes as the user drags the handle. However, although the resize cursor appears when I hover over the handle, dragging it doesn't seem to have any effect on the panes' sizes.
Here's the code:


const resizeHandle1 = document.querySelector("#pane1 .resize-handle");
const resizeHandle2 = document.querySelector("#pane2 .resize-handle");
const pane1 = document.getElementById("pane1");
const pane2 = document.getElementById("pane2");
let isResizing = false;

resizeHandle1.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  isResizing = true;
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", resizePane1);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopResize);
});

resizeHandle2.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  isResizing = true;
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", resizePane2);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopResize);
});

function resizePane1(e) {
  if (isResizing) {
    const offsetRight = document.body.offsetWidth - e.clientX;
    pane1.style.width = `calc(100% - ${offsetRight}px)`;
  }
}

function resizePane2(e) {
  if (isResizing) {
    const offsetLeft = e.clientX;
    pane2.style.width = `calc(${offsetLeft}px - 10px)`;
  }
}

function stopResize() {
  isResizing = false;
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resizePane1);
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resizePane2);
}
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.pane {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.resize-handle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: col-resize;
  background: #ddd;
  top: 0;
  right: -5px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div id="pane1" class="pane">
    <div class="resize-handle"></div>
    Pane 1
  </div>
  <div id="pane2" class="pane">
    <div class="resize-handle"></div>
    Pane 2
  </div>
</div>




Remove second <div class="resize-handle"></div> with js events and also "flex: 1" from .pane
